# How to List Parameters for teleop_twist_keyboard Node in ROS 2?

Tags: ros2, turtlebot, teleop

I'm currently working with the `teleop_twist_keyboard` node in ROS 2 and am looking to fine-tune its performance for a project. Specifically, I need to list and the maximum published speeds when using the keyboard teleoperation.

I assume (maybe wrong) that the max linear and max angular velocities are set with parameters. I tried both `ros2 param list` and `ros2 param list /teleop_twist_keyboard` but it shows the following exception.

```
Exception while calling service of node '/teleop_twist_keyboard': None
```

**What is the right way to list all the parameters for the `teleop_twist_keyboard` node?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The question is simplified to be more specific.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Assuming `teleop_twist_keyboard` is the name of your node, you are using [the correct command](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Using-ros2-param.html#ros2-param-list). Please try again. I have faced this error only a few times, but it is rare.